# How to populate a Div using Jquery and Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am slightly confused how to populate the div as seen in the example, say I have the following dropdown and Div:

```
<div id='drop'>
    <select name='option'>
        <option value="Opt1">Opt1</option>
        <option value="Opt2">Opt2</option>
        <option value="Opt3">Opt3</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id = 'NewContent'>

</div>
```

And then the following JS:

```
$('select[name="option"]').change(function() {
   $('#NewContent').html(this.value);
});
```

how would I put the following into the Div:

```
<form>
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>
```

if the user were to select Opt2 for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like the following jQuery to append the form:

```
$('select[name="option"]').change(function () {
    if (this.value == 'Opt2') {
        var form = $('#test');
        if (form.length == 0) {
            $('#NewContent').html('<form id="test">First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname"></form>');
        }
    }
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/s9hFP/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are after?

```
$('select[name="option"]').change(function() {
   if($( "select.foo option:selected").val() == 'Opt2'){
       $('#NewContent').html('<form> \
                              First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br> \
                              Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname"> \
                              </form>');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

Change your html to:

```
<div style="display:none" id="hold">
    <form>
    First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname">
    </form>
 <div>
```

And do this:

```
$('select[name="option"]').change(function() {
    if($(this).val()=="Opt2"){
       $('#NewContent').html($('#hold').html());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Chris's solution is ok.
Another approach is to already include html in NewContent div:

```
<div id = 'NewContent'>
 <form>
   First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
   Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname">
  </form>
</div>
```

And then hide by css:

```
#NewContent form {
    display:none;
}
```

So when you click :

```
$('select[name="option"]').change(function() {
   $( 'form', '#NewContent').show();
});
```